# How to overwrite css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've an alert div, once it pops up I've to wait till it disappear completely before the next animation can occur. Is there any way to ignore/cancel the animation and let it be overwritten with new one? So it re-alert very time I hover the button.

```
$('.button').hover(function () {
  $('#alert-me').show();
  $("#alert-me").fadeOut(6000);
});


<div class="hidden-div" id="alert-me">
     <b> hello! </b>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use 'finish()' of jquery to end a jquery animation

Comment: @ShobhitSrivastava Yeah thanks :) worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option would be to `.finish()` the animation before you `.show()` it.

### Working Example:

```js
$('.button').hover(function () {
  $('#alert-me').finish().show();
  $("#alert-me").fadeOut(6000);
});
```

```css
.hidden-div {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button">button</div>

<div class="hidden-div" id="alert-me">
     <b> hello! </b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the callback of `show()` method you can hide it.

```
$('.button').hover(function () {
  $('#alert-me').show(function(){
    $("#alert-me").fadeOut(6000);
  });

});
```